# Any Catalyst driver for ATi Mobility Radeon HD 2300 on Win 7 32b?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ati-mobility-radeon

For more than 6 months, I've had this problem. I can't seem to find a display driver for my **ATi Mobility Radeon HD 2300** specific for the Windows 7 32bit.

I don't necessarily need official drivers.. any WORKING modded drivers will also be perfect. I just need to get the Catalyst to run along with that driver.

The current driver is the one from windows update ( a WDDM 1.1 driver ) that obviously has no catalyst support so I removed it using Driver Sweeper.

I tried the [DNA-ATi 10.10e4](http://donotargue.com/note/dna-ati-10-10e-4/) modded drivers but its driver doesn't install and manually installing the INF files from it doesn't start my driver up either! (after reboot, device manager shows "windows has stopped the driver because it reported an error")

My Laptop is Acer Aspire 5910G and the OEM doesn't have the driver now either.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of laptop manufacturers don't allow installing of drivers other than the ones that they provided. You'll have to mod ATI/AMD's drivers to "force" it to install in your laptop.

Download the latest drivers for your ATI/AMD card here: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

Then use **[Mobility Modder](http://www.hardwareheaven.com/modtool.php)**, to modify the driver to work with your laptop.

Comment: tried all these.. it just doesn't seem to work with my ATi Radeon HD 2300 and the latest drivers that I mod.. I get BSODs.. seems like its goodbye to my old gpu here..

Comment: @Power-Inside Are you using the 'legacy' drivers? If the 'legacy' or non-legacy 10.x versions don't work, try modding the latest 9.x 'legacy' version. 'Legacy' drivers download links here: (Windows Vista or 7 32-bit) http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Legacy/previous/Pages/radeonaiw_vista32.aspx

Comment: I just tried the legacy drivers.. 8.10, 9.11, 10.2, none of these install (both unmodded and modded)

Answer (score 0):

Modded driver for **ATI (Mobility) Radeon HD2300** and **X2300** cards with catalyst.

[AMD_Catalyst_13.5_Beta2_32&64bit(HD_2300,x2300).7z](https://yadi.sk/d/XsuUcf2TNsmmM)

Windows 7 32/64 and Windows 8 32/64 Support

Description:
http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?p=4606224#post4606224

Comment: Please don't recommend the use of 3 year old modified drivers.